# how to convert csv string into column and filter on by specific keyword in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to sum all the out(OUT) times from a csv string and show it in the next cell but is facing challenges. I am not able to process/split csv string. Need help on how to achieve this by excel formula or vba script.

csv string:

> 10:06:in(IN),11:36:out(OUT),11:42:in(IN),13:57:out(OUT),14:05:in(IN),14:23:out(OUT),14:38:in(IN),16:39:out(OUT),16:49:in(IN),17:19:out(OUT),17:28:in(IN),17:54:out(OUT),17:56:in(IN),18:08:in(IN),18:08:out(OUT),18:11:in(IN),18:12:out(OUT),18:21:out(OUT),18:24:in(IN),18:37:in(IN),18:37:out(OUT),18:57:out(OUT),18:58:in(IN),19:26:out(OUT),19:35:in(IN),20:18:out(OUT),

The string is from one cell.

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, start by looking up the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following UDF:

```
Public Function SumOutTimes(rin As Range) As Date
    Dim Kount As Long, OutTimes(), t As String
    t = rin.Text
    ary = Split(t, ",")
    Kount = 1

    For Each a In ary
        If InStr(1, a, "out") > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve OutTimes(1 To Kount)
                OutTimes(Kount) = Replace(a, ":out(OUT)", "")
                Kount = Kount + 1
        End If
    Next a

    For Each a In OutTimes
        SumOutTimes = SumOutTimes + TimeValue(a)
    Next a

End Function
```

For your data in cell **A1**

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=SumOutTimes(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Hi Gary, Please write the complete code as I am a beginner and unable to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you :

```
Sub test()

Dim Tx As String, A() As String, R()

Tx = Sheets("test").Cells(1, 1)
ReDim R(0)
A = Split(Tx, ",")

For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
    If Left(Right(A(i), 4), 2) <> "OU" Then
        'IN times
    Else
        'OUT times
        R(UBound(R)) = Left(A(i), 5)
        ReDim Preserve R(UBound(R) + 1)
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve R(UBound(R) - 1)

For i = LBound(R) To UBound(R)
    '---------------------------------------
    '------You can sum your times here------
    '---------------------------------------
Next i


End Sub
```

You juste have to read the CSV string and put it into Tx variable and choose how to sum your times!

Comment: Hi R3, You are awesome. God Bless You.It helped me a lot

Comment: You are very welcome, you'll see, VBA isn't that hard ;)
If your problem is solved, you can accept an answer by clicking on the tick just under the up and down vote, it'll become green and flag the subject as solved!